# Clarification in definition tangent vector

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.

A tangent vector of $M$ at $p$ is an equivalence class $[\gamma]$ of smooth curves $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ with $\gamma(0) =p$, where $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$ means that there is a chart $\phi$ around $p$ such that $(\phi\circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (\phi\circ \gamma_2)'(0)$.

**Question**: Is $\epsilon > 0$ fixed? Or is possible that $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2$ where the two curves have a different domain? I guess it's the latter, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, the domains may be different.

Comment: How are we even sure that the composition $\phi \circ \gamma_1$ is defined? Nothing says that $\gamma_1(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subseteq \operatorname{dom} \phi?$

Comment: You shrink the $\epsilon$s to make sure the images of both $\gamma_i$ are contained in the chart. After all, all you care about is differentiating at $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: So do we need to modify the definition so that it says that there is a chart $\phi$ around $p$ around $p$ such that $\phi \circ \gamma_1, \phi \circ \gamma_2$ are defined and that the derivatives at $0$ are equal, or do we say that there is a chart $\phi$ around $p$ such that $\phi\circ \gamma_1, \phi_\circ \gamma_2$ are defined when restricted to an appropriate smaller domain and such that the derivatives are equal at $0$?

Comment: The definition is fine as it stands. To define the equivalence relation you assume that things exist as stated.

Comment: "there is a chart $\phi$ around $p$ such that $(\phi\circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (\phi\circ \gamma_2)'(0)$" -> should we interpret this then as $(\phi \circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (\phi \circ \gamma_2)'(0)$ when the domains are restricted to a small enough neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: I think you're overdoing this. We already agreed that we've shrunk the domain so that you can compose with $\phi$. Done.

Comment: Ok, let me be a little more concrete. Suppose $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are defined on $(-1,1)$ and we have $\gamma_{1,2}((-1,1)) \not\subseteq \operatorname{dom} \phi$, but $\gamma_{1,2}((-1/2,1/2)) \subseteq \operatorname{dom} \phi$ such that $\phi\circ\gamma_1\vert_{(-1/2,1/2)}'(0) = \phi\circ\gamma_2\vert_{(-1/2,1/2)}'(0) $. Is $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuitive picture of "curves having the same velocity at a given point" is pretty clear, but, as you point out, there are some technical obstacles to making it precise. There are a number of equivalent constructions. Here's one recipe (among many others):

Choose $p\in M$.

Choose a chart $\varphi:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ containing $p$.

Consider the set of curves $\gamma:I\to M$ where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an interval containing $0$ and $\gamma(0)=p$.

Define an equivalence as follows: Given $\gamma_1:I_1\to M$, and $\gamma_2:I_2\to M$ as above, say $\gamma_1\sim\gamma_2$ if there are restrictions of domain to open intervals $J_1\subseteq I_1$, $J_2\subseteq I_2$ containing $0$ such that $\gamma_1|_{J_1}$ and $\gamma_1|_{J_2}$ both map into $U$ and $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\varphi(\gamma_1|_{J_2}(t))\right|_{t=0}=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\varphi(\gamma_2|_{J_2}(t))\right|_{t=0}$ in the vector calculus sense.

From then, it needs to be checked that these restrictions always exist, and that the equivalence is independent of the choice of restriction, and that the equivalence classes are independent of the choice of chart.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean "it must be checked that these restrictions always exist"?

Comment: That $J_1$ and $J_2$ always exist, i.e. it is always possible to restrict the domain of a curve (in the class of interest) to fall entirely within the chart domain $U$. This ensures that every curve belongs to a nontrivial equivalence class.

Comment: Ah, this is because of continuity right? We have that $\gamma: I \to M$ is continuous, so $\gamma^{-1}(U)$ is open (since $U \subseteq M$ is open). Since $0 \in \gamma^{-1}(U)$, this means that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subseteq \gamma^{-1}(U)$ and then $\gamma(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subseteq U$.

Comment: Yes. By "curve" I mean a _smooth_ map from $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to $M$..

Comment: Yes, so smooth implies continuity so my argument works?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This perfectly answered my concerns.